# Inherit from QTime in order to customize time format

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to extend the `QTime` class in order to override the `toString()` function.

----EDIT-----
What I really need is a clean way to display only tenths/hudredths of second and not also milliseconds. My current solution is something like:

```
QString original = qtime.toString("ss.zzz");
QString tenths = original.left(original.size() - 2);  // discards hundredths and msecs
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
QString tenths = fooTime.myToString("ss.x");  // discards hundredths and msecs
```

---EDIT----

This class looks like the following:

```
class FooTime : public QTime
{
public:
    FooTime()
    {}

    FooTime(int h, int m, int s = 0, int ms = 0)
    : QTime(h, m, s, ms)
    {}

    QString toString(const QString& format) const // the function I need to override
    {
        return format + " foo";
    }

    FooTime& operator=(const FooTime& t)
    {
        // ??? see below.
    }
};
```

Unfortunately `QTime` has a tricky behavior in these functions:

```
class QTime
{
    ...
    QTime addMSecs(int ms) const;
    QTime addSecs(int s) const;
    ...
}
```

So actually I can't write the following code:

```
...
FooTime t(0, 0);
t = t.addMSecs(1000);  // compile error, no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'FooTime' and 'QTime')
```

The problem is that a `FooTime` is a `QTime`, but a `QTime` is not a `FooTime`.

How can I override the `FooTime` operator `=` in order to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you need to override the toString, just use one of the formatting functions

Comment: Because I'd like to use a different format not provided by default.

Comment: You cannot override `QTime::toString()` function because it is not a virtual function.

Comment: @vahancho Ops, that's a problem. But I can add a new `myToString()` function, right?

Comment: @ital, yes, you can, but for what?:) Please explain what a special format you need, that cannot be achieved with QTime class?

Comment: @vahancho I'd like to display only tenths/hundredths of second and not also milliseconds. Of course I can extract a substring from the string returned by `QTime::toString()`, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @ital, I would write a static function `static QString specialTime(const QTime &time)` that will do the job. For example: `return QString::number(time.msec() * 10);` or so.

Comment: This is bad question since you are asking: how to fix your crappy solution of some mysterious or secret problem, instead explain what is your problem (then as a bonus option you should explain how you have tried to solve it and it didn't work).

Comment: I recommend to start question from showing an example of some time and what string you are trying to have from it.

Comment: @MarekR You are right, look at the edited question. I'll consider to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I override the FooTime operator = in order to solve this
>   problems?

this should suffice:

```
class FooTime : public QTime
{
public:
    FooTime& operator=(const QTime& t)
    {
        QTime::operator=(t);
        /* Assign other things if there is a need, manage memory etc,
           but it seems that there are no members in FooTime,
           just functions, so it's all. */
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The derivation from `QTime` is an entirely wrong approach. If you need to format the time differently, simply write a stand-alone function:

```
QString myTimeFormat(const QTime & time) {
  const QString str = time.toString("ss.zzz");
  return str.left(str.size() - 2);
}
```

Object orientation isn't a universal hammer. Sometimes a plain old function will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing and overriding is pointless here simple function will do the job.
I would do this like that (as a static class method or as global function).

```
QString myTimeFormat(const QTime & time) {
  QString result = QString("%1.%2").arg(time.second())
                                   .arg((time.msec()+50)/100);
  return result;
}
```